# Ubuntu: apt-get "Building Dependency Tree" is extremely slow

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

On a new Ubuntu Server 12.10 installation, running `apt-get install` results in *extremely slow* progress while "Building dependency tree". The process has been going for about 15 minutes with about 17% progress.

Any ideas why this might be taking so incredibly long??

Comment: What's your root filesystem? btrfs?

Comment: Also, have you tried `sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/*.bin`

Comment: Oof this is old and I'm still facing it on Ubuntu 22, been 2 hours and now it's 62% xD

Answer (score -1):

Have you added any non-standard repositories? Even then it should eventually pass over anything that doesn't respond.

Does it ever actually finish? Or does it hang forever?

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers.